# Attach Screenshot in ALM Test Case step level using QuerySerge

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, alm, hp-quality-center

can we execute Test Cases and attach screenshot in ALM/HPQC using QuerySerge Tool.
We are trying to implement automation and want to execute the Test case and attach screenshot using the tool. I am aware that we can connect the QC and QuerySerge. But not finding any useful info regarding my requirement of running the Test Case and attaching the screenshot. Please share any useful info or any links that will help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please be more specific on your query? Which version of QC are you using? Old HP or the new micro focus version?

On the MicroFocus site you have the complete userguide. For instance you can use different kind of scripting (SQL query or API).
I am using REST API and able to connect, update test results and attachment of whatever type.

Please check on the microfocus if you can find what is needed for your QuerySerge (not sure on that):

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/15.5-15.5.1/online_help/Content/APIs/API_ALM_REST_Site_Admin.htm

Hope that help and clarify your question.
Have a nice day.